# What is a Metaphor for "Being Thrown Into a Completely New Environment"

Tags: metaphors

I am trying to convey how I was thrown into a completely new environment in my essay. What would be a good metaphorical representation of that?

Comment: "Thrown for a loop" *might* fit, but it also can refer to other disorienting situations.

Comment: This is POB, but I'll throw in ***out of one's element***.

Comment: *taken out of your [comfort zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comfort_zone)*

Comment: I think it depends on how you felt about it. "One small step for a man" and "I think we're not in Kansas any more" have very different connotations.

Comment: It can also be called a sea change. Given the context, it seems appropriate.

Comment: Is a description of the new environment relative? How did it compare to the one you left? Were you "Tossed into a tempest" or "Dropped into a void?"

Answer (score 10):

You could say...

- It was *a baptism of fire*.
- I was *thrown in at the deep end*.

There's also a phrase, *sink or swim*, which means roughly the same thing.

Answer (score 7):

A metaphor for "to be thrown into a completely new environment", I would suggest

- "to feel like a fish out of water"

> to feel awkward because you are not familiar with a situation or because you are very different from the people around you.

"All the other children in the school had rich, middle-class parents, and she was beginning to feel like a fish out of water." [The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+like+a+fish+out+of+water)

Comment: "Well, *this* is a whole different kettle of fish".

Answer (score 6):

In Australia, there's "Thrown in at the deep end", meaning someone being thrown into the deep end of a pool, and having to learn to swim rather suddenly because they can't just stand on the bottom of the pool and still breathe.

I don't know if it's used outside Australia.

Comment: We use that in the UK too. We both mentioned it at the same time.

Comment: America is no different. We use it there too. But we don't use a double preposition. Just "Thrown in the deep end."

Comment: can confirm @CarlSmith's comment that it's in common usage in the UK for just this situation.